# How can I program life-like random dice?

Tags: ios, random, game-physics, arkit, dice

Id like to make a dice game but i have a few questions about the randomness for dice. 
If possible id like to use the same randomness that there is in the real world.
the app will be for ios and I will be coding it in swift using some ar kits from apple.
Id like to know if it would be better to make a algorithm for the roll or if I should let the user shake/roll a 3d dice the game(relying on physics laws for the roll).
Which of these will replicate real world randomness?

Thakns!

Comment: relying on physics laws for the roll would be a better option btw this question is too broad to be acceptable by the SO standards.

Comment: @Vcxsta You can use the random number generation for this purpose. This code can provide you a random number smaller than 6. let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))

Comment: The code for a *realistic* simulation of a physical die roll would exceed in both length and difficulty the game code you are hoping to write by orders of magnitude (and would itself probably require a pseudo-random number generator in setting up the initial conditions). Just use the built-in random number generator. Anything else would be a waste of programmer time.

Comment: Never, ever, "roll your own" random number generators or crypto. Use a trusted library that implements well-known algorithms and use it exactly as directed. Any "improvement" you try to add will very likely break it.

Answer (score 3):

A "real world randomness" for something as throwing a dice only means "not having enough information to predict the result". It is hard to include precision of your throw, effect of air flow and then even more the impurity of your dice and material it is bouncing off.

The same thing may not happen in computer program by itself. No matter the physics, for 2 situations with same input data you will get the same output. So you need a random at some point or you need user interaction.

For user interaction you may again have an issue because you may not have enough input data to generate a random event. For instance this event is seeded by user making a swipe gesture on the screen. Now this specific user is training to always make a 100px drag when performing a gesture. He does not succeed perfectly but he may still be seeding your event so close that he gets a 3/6 chance to throw his value instead of 1/6.

In the end even if user interaction is random enough you may by mistake create your environment so that it is balanced and some results may occur more often.

But even if all is perfect and you manage to create a perfect random your users may not be satisfied with it. In a complete random scenario things may happen such as throwing the same value 20 times in a row. Or it might happen you will not throw the value you need 20 times in a row. Physically throwing a dice seeing such even will not be an issue but I guarantee that if someone sees that in an application he will claim it is bugged, balanced...

Random is in general a huge issue. It is usually too important to be let to chance. Most just want a series of nicely distributed values from which they can not find an algorithm to predict the next value.

So none will replicate real world randomness. You need to choose depending on what you expect your users need.